# Show that graph with $n$ vertices is a tree if it has has no cycle and has $n-1$ edges

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof, trees

I have an assignment:

> Show that an $n$-vertex graph $G$ is a tree if and only if $G$ has no cycle and has $n − 1$ edges.

And I am kind of stuck on it right now (I was never good at proofs in general).

My current idea is this:

Suppose that graph $G$ is a tree (connected, acyclic graph) with $n$ vertices and $n - 1$ edges.
Since $G$ is a tree, there exists a path between any pair of vertices.
Let $uv \in E(G)$ s.t. there is path between $u$ and $v$.
Now add an edge between $u$ and $v$. G now contains $n - 1 + 1 = n$ edges and there are now two paths between $u$ and $v$. Connecting these paths will create a cycle $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is no longer a tree.

But I don't know if that even makes any sense. And if it makes sense, is it enough?

I am also pretty sure that there is a better way of proving this, but I just can't think of anything.

Comment: In order to prove your statement you need to first show that if $G$ is a tree then it has no cycles and $n-1$ edges, and then show that if it has no cycles and $n-1$ edges then it is a tree. You can't assume that $G$ is a tree with $n-1$ edges, since then you are assuming what you want to prove. Here is a related post that may be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834816/show-that-a-connected-graph-on-n-vertices-is-a-tree-if-and-only-if-it-has-n-1?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Your argument doesn't really make sense. You're starting off your proof by assuming that $G$ is a tree and that it has $n-1$ edges which are basically both the directions of the statement you want to prove. You should first start with the assumption that $G$ is a tree and prove that it has $n-1$ edges and then do the opposite by assuming that $G$ is acyclic and has $n-1$ edges and prove that it is a tree.

Here are some hints:

- For the ($\implies$) direction: use induction on $n$. Remove a leaf from $G$ and use the inductive hypothesis.
- For the ($\impliedby$) direction: assume that $G$ has $k$ connected components. Since it's acyclic, every connected component is a tree. How many edges does $G$ have? (use the forward implication)

Comment: Ok. I get the first part. But I am kinda lost at the second one. $G$ has $k$ components. So it has $n - k$ edges. Each component is a tree. So I need to add $k - 1$ edges in order to "connect" them all into a single tree? Or what am I missing?

Comment: @Stratos The fact that it has $n-k$ edges gives you that $k=1$. $k=1$ means the graph is connected. Connected + acyclic $\implies$ tree. Notice that the fact that $G$ has $n-k$ edges comes from the fact that every component is a tree.

Comment: Go it. I got confused with the acyclic part, because I was thinking about $G$ being a connected graph with $n-1$ edges and that it has a cycle (is not a tree). And removing the cycle would lead to $n-2$ edges, which can't be a connected graph and can't be a tree.